# Add shadow slowly using CSS3

Tags: jquery, css

I have a shadow added to the header of the site using jquery when scrolling down. However I would like to "fade in" the shadow when the class is added and fade out when removed.

Could that be done using CSS3?

This is the class added/removed when scrolling.

```
.header_shadow{-webkit-box-shadow: 0 10px 6px -6px #777;-moz-box-shadow: 0 10px 6px -6px #777;box-shadow: 0 10px 6px -6px #777;}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use CSS transitions (add your prefixes as you will):

```
.header_shadow { 
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 #777;
    transition: box-shadow 3s ease-in-out;
}

.header_shadow.addshadow {
    box-shadow: 0 10px 6px -6px #777;
}
```

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/edelman/df43C/)

Comment: That works for adding the shadows, but when removing the class the shadow disappears with no "animation".

Comment: actually, it does. just remove the class. I updated the fiddle to reflect this.

Comment: You are right! Thanks! I put the transition in the "starting" class and adding/removing the shadow class works like a charm. Thanks Jason!

Answer (score -1):

Like this way [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/w5aAn/1037/)

```
$('#box').mouseover(function() {
      $(this).delay(200).animate({
        'boxShadowX': '10px',
        'boxShadowY':'10px',
        'boxShadowBlur': '20px'
    });
});

$('#box').mouseout(function() {
      $(this).delay(200).animate({
        'boxShadowX': '0px',
        'boxShadowY':'0px',
        'boxShadowBlur': '0px'
    });
});
```

​